# Python 2.7: How to make data points appear on an empty canvas plot window

Tags: python, canvas, plot

I want to plot xcoord vs. ycoord on a canvas. What I get right now is only an empty plot window (1 high x 1 wide) . 
How can I make the datapoints appear in the plot window? 
I have checked the xcoord and ycoord arrays. They exist and they are correct.

```
class SurveyRoute(SurveyPlotWidget):
"""docstring for SurveyRoute"""

def __init__(self, survey_name, parent=None, model=None):
    self.survey_name = survey_name
    SurveyPlotWidget.__init__(self, parent, model)

def read_coordinate_file(self, survey_name):
    self.coords = station_coordinates.get_coordinates_all(survey_name)
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.coords,index=['UTM X','UTM Y','depth']) 
    df = DataFrame.transpose(df)
    self.xcoord = df['UTM X'].values.tolist() 
    self.ycoord = df['UTM Y'].values.tolist()
    print self.xcoord

def on_hover(self, event):
    self.fig_text.set_text('')
    contains, attrd = self.points.contains(event)
    if contains == True:
        ind = attrd['ind'][0]
        self.fig_text.set_text('bm {}'.format(self.model.benchmarks[ind]))

    self.canvas.draw()

def plot_coords(self):        
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(self.xcoord, self.ycoord, marker='o', ms=10, linestyle='', alpha=1.0, color='r', picker = True)[0]
    plt.xlabel('UTM x-coordinate')
    plt.ylabel('UTM y-coordinate')

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_hover)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

## running the class

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

obj = SurveyRoute('mikkel')
obj.read_coordinate_file('mikkel')
obj.plot_coords()

obj.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

should be removed and

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_hover)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

should be substituted by

```
self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_hover)
self.canvas.draw()
```